# iOS 10 iPhone 6S Play Haptic feedback or vibrate using taptic engine

Tags: ios, iphone

Iphone6s has taptic engine or not, can I use a public API called `UIFeedbackGenerator` to access it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

iPhone 7 has a more precise, more flexible Taptic Engine than iPhone 6s — you can use the [`UIFeedbackGenerator`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uifeedbackgenerator) class cluster to get at the richer vocabulary of haptic feedback signals that iPhone 7 supports, but these APIs have no effect on iPhone 6s (or other devices).

iPhone 6s still has a Taptic Engine, but it's not as capable as the newer one — it supports only the haptic signals associated with 3D Touch features. However, it is possible to use those in your app:

- to build a standard Peek/Pop UI (haptics included) into your app, use standard views that already do it (like table and collection views), set peek/pop segues in your storyboard, and/or adopt the [`UIViewControllerPreviewing`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontrollerpreviewing) and [`UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontrollerpreviewingdelegate) protocols in your view controller. You can do this in iOS 9.
- to provide peek/pop gesture support — including the accompanying haptic feedback — without a UI, or with your own custom UI, use the [`UIPreviewInteraction`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipreviewinteraction) class and its [delegate protocol](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipreviewinteractiondelegate). This part requires iOS 10.

For more info about peek/pop, 3D Touch, and haptics in general, see the WWDC16 session ["A Peek at 3D Touch"](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/228/) and Apple's guide to [Adopting 3D Touch on iPhone](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Adopting3DTouchOniPhone/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016543).

Answer (score 18):

Haptic feedback engine have been introduced in iPhone7/7+ and you can use it via UIFeedbackGenerator, here's an example:

```
let generator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .heavy)
generator.prepare()

generator.impactOccurred()
```

As for iPhone 6S/6S I've found kind of fallback, please try it and describe the experience if you do have the device:

```
import AudioToolbox


AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1519) // Actuate `Peek` feedback (weak boom)
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1520) // Actuate `Pop` feedback (strong boom)
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1521) // Actuate `Nope` feedback (series of three weak booms)
```

I've tried to summarize everything I found with regards to the Haptic feedback here: 
http://www.mikitamanko.com/blog/2017/01/29/haptic-feedback-with-uifeedbackgenerator/